# MySQL) How to remove duplicated rows working with WHILE loop?

Tags: mysql, loops, join, subquery, procedure

I have a table called `cart` and an empty table `sort` in database. My goal is to transmit & split values in comma spread from one table to another like this:

```
(table cart)
id |  food
---+--------------
1  | Carrots, Cucumbers 
2  | Dandelions 
3  | Salmons    
4  | Cucumbers, Potatoes    
5  | Tomatoes

(table sort after run query)
id |  food
---+--------------
1  | Carrots    
1  | Cucumbers  
2  | Dandelions 
3  | Salmons    
4  | Cucumbers  
4  | Potatoes   
5  | Tomatoes
```

An issue is, it seems like the keywords `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` won't work properly inside of the `WHILE` clause. When I run my query, MySQL inserts a whole list of values multiple times based on a total of `id` count.

Have a look at this query:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION fx_splitString(columnName TEXT, pos INT)
    RETURNS TEXT
    RETURN TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(columnName, ',', pos), ',', -1)) //
CREATE PROCEDURE pd_splitRow()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE rowToll INT;    
        SET rowToll = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM cart);
        SET @outerCount = 1;
        WHILE @outerCount <= rowToll DO
            INSERT INTO sort (id, food)
                SELECT DISTINCT id, fx_splitString(food, @stringToll) FROM cart; 
            SET @outerCount = @outerCount + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
CALL pd_splitRow();
```

Now I'm trying to find other ways to accomplish this but none of these work.

---

### Try 1: Nested Loop

This idea is aborted because MySQL won't allow to set multiple rows. I can't use to create variable

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row    0.016 sec

```
DECLARE rowToll INT;    
SET rowToll = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM cart);
SET @stringToll = (SELECT LENGTH(food) - LENGTH(REPLACE(food, ',', '')) + 1 FROM cart); /* error */
SET @outerCount = 1;
SET @innerCount = 1;
WHILE @outerCount <= rowToll DO

    WHILE @innerCount <= @stringToll DO
        INSERT INTO sort (id, food)
            SELECT DISTINCT id, fx_splitString(food, @stringToll) FROM cart; 
        SET @innerCount = @innerCount + 1;
    END WHILE;

    SET @outerCount = @outerCount + 1;
END WHILE;
```

---

### Try 2: Self Join

This one simply does not insert any of values from `cart` table.

```
WHILE @begin <= rowCount DO
    INSERT INTO sort (id, food)
        SELECT DISTINCT cte1.id, fx_splitString(cte1.food, @begin) FROM cart cte1
        INNER JOIN cart cte2 ON cte1.id = cte2.id AND cte1.food = cte2.food; 
        SET @begin = @begin + 1;
END WHILE;
```

I could just use in the examples from the other guys' query but I want to create my own for improving skills.

Are there any ways to group the rows working with `WHILE` loop?

Comment: The function isn't useful in my view - think about using limit and offset to read a row at a time and shuffling the tokens out.

Comment: @P.Salmon The function in the post is just for looking more better. Anyway, thank you for giving the tips. I'm gonna try with that :>

Comment: MySQL version ? Maximal amount of separate values in a field?

Comment: @Akina The version is 8.0.19. And I don't need the amount of limited values.